# C# WPF DataGrid get row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a C# WPF project and I use a DataGrid (not DataGridView)

I need to get a row from the DataGrid using

```
myGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem
```

My problem is that the result is always null - even though there are rows(items) and columns in the grid.

Here is what I can see in Debugger output:

```
myGrid.Items.Count
16

myGrid.Items[0]
{Certificate.Gasbottle}
    BottleNr: "******"
    BottleNrVariable: "$BottlenumberCO2CH4H2S"
    Gasname: "CO2/CH4/H2S"
    
myGrid.Items[1]
{Certificate.Gasbottle}
    BottleNr: "75436"
    BottleNrVariable: "$BottlenumberCO"
    Gasname: " CO"

Problem:    
(DataGridRow)myGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myGrid.Items[1]);
null      <--- why null? myGrid.Items[1] does exist... (I also get this for all other items)
```

I also get null if I use FromIndex instead of FromItem:

```
DataGridRow row  = myGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1)
```

Some more information:
I want to change backcolor of a row.

in Button click event I set .ItemsSource like so:

```
ObservableCollection<Gasbottle> Gasbottles = new ObservableCollection<Gasbottle>();

...here I fill Gasbottles ObservableCollection

//then Display ObservableCollection - this works
GasbottleGrid.ItemsSource = Gasbottles;
 
 
...now try to find row by its index or by item and set its backcolor color
//row by index: first row in Grid
//
int currentRowIndex = 0; /or 1 or 2...doesnt matter
DataGridRow dgrow = (DataGridRow)GasbottleGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currentRowIndex);

//try to set color : NULL error because dgrow is NULL
dgrow.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
```

Comment: Where are you calling `ContainerFromItem` and where and how do you set the `ItemsSource` property?

Comment: In order to get help, you must post more code related to the context. What you have posted so far is totally useless. We must see how and with what you populate the DataGrid and where and when you are trying to get the containers. Usually you don't need access to the containers from codebehind, so this could be another hint that you are doing things generally wrong. This mean instead of exclusively describing what's not working you must always describe the bigger goal too. Your current solution might be wrong too, so fixing it may not help you at all. But without details nobody can assist you.

Comment: Please post complete code and not this rubbish snippets. We are all developers and know how to read code. How to identify implementation errors if you don't show the code? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are lucky that this question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rows as follows:

```
var itemsSource = myGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    
if (itemsSource != null)
{
   foreach (var item in itemsSource)
   {
       DataGridRow row = myGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
    
   }
}
```

To get a specific row,

```
var itemsSource = dataGrid.ItemsSource as IList;
    
if (itemsSource != null && itemsSource.Count > 1)
{
   var item = itemsSource[1];
   DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
    
}
```

Comment: I need a specifc row, not all

Comment: It depends on your ItemSource. If you have a list, use IList instead of IEnumerable to get item at desired index.

Comment: I have used "var itemsSource = dataGrid.ItemsSource as IList; "

"item" contains valid data - but "DataGridRow row" is again null

Comment: ok, that means, you need to share more code. Itemsource details and where do you set your itemssource. Why do you need DataGridRow ? normally you should not be reaching DataGridRow manually.

Comment: Is first approach with "IEnumerable" working somehow?

Comment: no, "IEnumerable" gives also "null"

Comment: I want to change backcolor of a row.

in Button click event I set .ItemsSource like so:

ObservableCollection<Gasbottle> Gasbottles = new ObservableCollection<Gasbottle>();

...fill Gasbottles ObservableCollection

//Display ObservableCollection - this works:
GasbottleGrid.ItemsSource = Gasbottles;<br>int currentRowIndex = 1;
DataGridRow dgrow = (DataGridRow)NDIRGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currentRowIndex);

//NULL error because dgrow is NULL
dgrow.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;

Comment: This not the way of working in WPF. You should be using datatemplates depending on your business logic. Consider using MVVM and templates.